# What is the meaning of "(." and ".)" in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have found this PL/SQL code but I can't find in Oracle documentation to be valid:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE hard_priv AS
BEGIN
    HTP.htmlOpen;
    HTP.headOpen;
    HTP.title (.Account Information.);
    HTP.headClose;
    HTP.bodyOpen;
    HTP.br;
    HTP.print('User ID: ' ||
               OWA_SEC.get_user_id || '');
    HTP.print('User Password: ' ||
               OWA_SEC.get_password || '');
    HTP.br;
    HTP.bodyClose;
    HTP.htmlClose;
END hard_priv;
END uu_hr_pkg;
```

Comment: did you try running it without `. .` in htp.title? It is just going to display the text, whatever put in the `()` except declaring datatypes

Comment: Has the code been copied and pasted to something that replaced single quotes with smart quotes (e.g. Word); and then copied to something that doesn't understand those and shows periods instead (e.g. vim)? Pretty sure I've seen that before... But they should be quotes, periods are clearly not valid or meaningful there.

Comment: Ultimately, the question is "Does it compile?", and the answer is "No". [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4d7d44/1).

Answer (score 2):

## "`(.`" and "`.)`" is not PLSQL syntax.

So it cannot compile.

This simple:

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('this is the right syntax');
  dbms_output.put_line(.this_dont_work.);
end;
/
```

Gives a compilation error like that:

> ```
> SQL> @a
> dbms_output.put_line(.this_dont_work.);
>                      *
> ERROR at line 3:
> ORA-06550: line 3, column 26:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following:
> ( ) - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> table continue avg count current exists max min prior sql
> stddev sum variance execute multiset the both leading
> trailing forall merge year month day hour minute second
> timezone_hour timezone_minute timezone_region timezone_abbr
> time timestamp interval date
> ```

In the real world, you must replace them with `'`; your thing should be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE hard_priv AS
BEGIN
  HTP.htmlOpen;
  HTP.headOpen;
  HTP.title ('Account Information');
  HTP.headClose;
....
```

Comment: Unfortunately SQL Fiddle does not work with Oracle anymore.  Although the original code will create a compilation error, what you're seeing in SQL Fiddle is the server failing.

Comment: Oh thanks @JonHeller, yeah, I thought this could be something temporarily wrong. I updated with a simple example.